# Get Window Coordinates of Touch in Gesture Recognizer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm dragging a CALayer out of one UIView to another using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. In the UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed method, I am calling to move the CALayer with

```
var touchLocation = recognizer.locationInView(recognizer.view)
self.panForTranslation(touchLocation)
```

However touchLocation is returning the CALayers position relative to it's frame, not the screen coordinates.

How can I get a UITouch location of the exact point the finger is on screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var touchLocation = recognizer.locationInView(recognizer.view.window)
self.panForTranslation(touchLocation)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I'm surprised an answer this simple hasn't been posted on the other questions I've seen with this same issue.